# BehaviorSubject undefined in constructor

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I have a problem with some behaviorsubjects.

I have a service :

```
import{ Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class BoutonImprimerGriseService {

    boutonImprimerGrise = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
    boutonImprimerGriseChanged$ = this.boutonImprimerGrise.asObservable();

    boutonMettreAZeroGrise = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
    boutonMettreAZeroGriseChanged$ = this.boutonMettreAZeroGrise.asObservable();

}
```

and I use it in a component :

```
export class GestionCompteursComponent {

boutonImprimerGrise: boolean;
boutonMettreAZeroGrise: boolean;

private _boutonImprimerGriseSubscription: Subscription;
private _boutonMettreAZeroSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(private _boutonImprimerGriseService: BoutonImprimerGriseService)
{
    this._boutonImprimerGriseSubscription = this._boutonImprimerGriseService.boutonImprimerGriseChanged$.subscribe(
        value => {
            console.log(value);
            this.boutonImprimerGrise = value;
        }
    );
    this._boutonMettreAZeroSubscription = this._boutonImprimerGriseService.boutonMettreAZeroGriseChanged$.subscribe(
        value => {
            console.log(value);
            this.boutonMettreAZeroGrise = value;
        }
    );
}
}
```

The problem is when I log the values of the observables in the constructor, the first one, boutonImprimerGrise is always undefined even if it's set to true in my service and I don't understand why because the other one is true...

I logged everything I could but found nothing, if you have any idea you're welcomed :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

I typically like to define the variables within a service as private unless you need them not to be for some reason, and the other thing is to use typescript to define your boutonImprimerGrise variable as a BehaviorSubject. (Repeat for both declarations)

```js
private boutonImprimerGrise: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
boutonImprimerGriseChanged$ = this.boutonImprimerGrise.asObservable();
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it's just that changing the value in two different services at the same time...